# Show "view all" button if elements do not fit in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got two divs showing some of its content: https://jsfiddle.net/u1zmo2qn/2/

```
<div id="div1"> </div> <div id="div2"> </div>
```

Content:

```
<div class="el"> This is a square </div> ..
```

When you press the "View-ALL" button it shows the rest of the content.

The problem is that the divs may not need a "Show All" button if the content fits inside the div (like the yellow div in the jsFiddle link).

How would I make it that the "Show Everything" button only shows if neccessarryy?

I would like it pure CSS if possible, but JS won't be the end of the world.

Is this possible?

The contents of the div will be constantly updating, and if possible I would rather not have to deal with screen resizes event(s) or doing something everytime contents of divs does change, to accomplish the "SHOW_MORE" button only when neccessarry.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is practically impossible to do with all the restrictions you have. In fact, it is impossible without Javascript. With some creativity though, you can make it so that you write the code once and don't have to think about whether to call an update function or not after the content is updated.

I have updated your fiddle to do what you want pretty convenient. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/k4x6rpvx/2/). The best part about this code is, even in the case where the content overflows due to the changes in the browser's width and height, it works. Be sure to test it in your target browsers.

I have used one of my favorite browser hacks located [here](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/). The code detects changes in the content's height. If the content overflows its parent, the "View All" button is shown. I had to restructure the html so that the tiles are inside a div with class `content` and "View All" buttons has a class `viewall`.